# How to add a URL parameter to current URL in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am currently in the Post component, and fetch data through Fetch Api from "/home" route.

```
 componentDidMount() {
   fetch('/home')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then((data)=> {
       console.log(data.ports)
       this.setState({ports: data.ports})
     })
     .catch(error =>console.log(error))
 }
```

Changing the response to json data, and set the state to be data.port_symbols. 
But now I want to use the data in the state to be the URL parameter, so I try the following code.

```
render() {   
return (
  <div>
    <h2>ports</h2> 
    <ul>
      {this.state.ports.map((port, index)=>          
         <li>
           <NavLink activeClassName='active-link' 
            to='/get_info/${port[0]}/${port[1]}'key={index}>
             {port[0]}/{port[1]}
           </NavLink>             
        </li>          
         )
      }   
    </ul>
```

So the question is,  `{port[0]}/{port[1]}` can be transferred into the value which stored in the state, but `${port[0]}/${port[1]}` can not be transferred into the value into the URL, the URL just displays `$%7Bport[0]/$%7Bport[1]%7D%7D`.

Can anyone help to figure out what the problem is and help to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: `to='/get_info/${port[0]}/${port[1]}'` these should be back ticks, not apostrophes

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to make this a template string:

```
   <NavLink activeClassName='active-link' 
    to=`/get_info/${port[0]}/${port[1]}` key={index}>
     {port[0]}/{port[1]}
   </NavLink>
```

the back ticks "`" will allow you to use the `${variable}` syntax.